# Is it possible to modularize a logic app ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

We know that way we can split a large ARM template into smaller templates (i.e. linked ARM templates), so that it is better manageable and maintainable. Can we do the same for logic apps ARM templates too. As far as the resources used in the logic apps ARM templates is concerned, it seems possible. But what about the entire flow? Can the logic apps flow be modularized too in the form of linked templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even if its a single resource definition you can modularize it with linked templates. The flow would be fairly straight forward:

1. move some parts to the nested templates if they are separate resources
2. invoke nested templates

if there is only 1 resource with big chunks of json you can do this:

1. identify individual json properties you want to offload
2. move them to nested templates as variables
3. make nested templates output those variables
4. invoke nested templates
5. pass nested templates output to appropriate json keys

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this..The first part makes sense, but the second one is not so clear to me. However, let me try this.

Comment: well, if your template contains output, you can get that output in any template, so you can effectively use that as a way to modularize stuff